# How can I dynamically load a JSON file inside an ECMAScript module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ecmascript-6, esmodules

I am doing:

```js
let filePath = '../../data/my-file.json'
import inputArray from filePath assert { type: 'json' }
```

This is the result I get:

```
file:///.../script.mjs:5
import inputArray from filePath assert { type: 'json' }
                       ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:119:18)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:483:14)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:67:21)
```

It works if I statically import the JSON file:

```js
import inputArray from './my-file.json' assert { type: 'json' }
```

Is there a way to dynamically import a JSON file inside ECMAScript modules?

Why is this happening?

I am using Node.js version **v18.7.0**.

Comment: Use `import(filePath)`?

Comment: You can't just pass a variable to import

Comment: https://v8.dev/features/import-assertions#dynamic-import()

Comment: just use `const data = await fetch(path).then(res => res.json())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way:

```js
let filePath = '../../data/my-file.json'

let arrayImport = await import(filePath, {
  assert: { type: "json" },
});
const inputArray = arrayImport.default 

console.log('result': inputArray)
```

More information here: [v8 - Dynamic import()](https://v8.dev/features/import-assertions#dynamic-import()).